# Filter based on Sql Value

Tags: tableau-api

This is my data source. My data has model number and company name, different companies can have the same model numbers as well as other models.

I want to add filter in tableau something like this

> sql (select Model Number from Table where company = 'Sony')

The data on tableau will be

```
Model Number     Company1 (sony)  Company2(Dell)  company3(Lenovo ) etc
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: Drag company name to filter and select value "Sony"

Answer (score 0):

If what you wanted was only to see Sony products, as Siva mentioned, you can just drag it to the filters shelf and select the value.  However, it sounds like you want to analyze data by both company and model number.  To get that:

1. Drag Model Number to the Rows shelf at the top
2. Drag Company to the Columns shelf at the top
3. Double-click your measure, such as Number of Records, to have Tableau add it to the visualization.

You can use the "show me" feature in the top right to pick different visualizations.  The training videos on the tableau website are a good way to get up and running quickly to solve other issues.